# Timezone is correctly stored in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, momentjs

I want to store a specific timezone/date on my database using Moment-timezone, but it keep storing as America's timezone.

Here's the code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var moment = require('moment-timezone');

var itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   time: { type: Date, default: moment().tz('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')}
});
```

The time in KL is `16:46` while America is at `08:46`

Comment: Mongodb times are stored in UTC only. It's not time in America. Time in KL is 8 hrs ahead of UTC. 16:46 at KL is 08:46 in UTC.

Comment: How would I solved this problem? add 8 hours?

Comment: Mongoose should convert the date back  to KL time zone. Don't worry about how it looks in db. What problems do you see ? If it's in UTC use moment to convert from UTC to KL time zone. Don't manually add 8 hrs.

Comment: @SagarReddy Could you share the answer so i could accept the answer?